# Disable spring property in app.yml is not possible

Tags: spring, spring-boot

After Upgrading Spring-boot version, we are having circular depenencies problems. So
I want to see this with the current version of Spring-boot **2.2.13.RELEASE**
So I added the following config to my application.yml.

```
spring.main.allow-circular-references = false
```

The problem is that it gives me an "Unknown property 'spring.main.allow-circular-references'"?
Is it Normal?

Kind regards,

Comment: That property was added in later versions hence it won't work in older versions. The only solution would be to set it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a YML, the "normal" way to declare this property is like this:

```
spring: 
  main:
    allow-circular-references: true
```

The default value since the last Spring version is **false**, so if you want to boot you need to start you need to set it to **true** (and fix it ;) )

Comment: Hello, yes I know but I want to disable it in the previous version 2.2.13 to see circular dependencies problems and resolve it before upgrading.

Comment: I think that you can't, this property has been added in the main configuration in Spring Boot 2.6, so you can upgrade and fix your errors one by one.   
Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.15/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.html?is-external=true#setAllowCircularReferences-boolean-